# Updating Android studio gives error/confilcts in installation

Tags: android-studio, runtime-error, updating

I have recently tried to update android studio, however whenever the updates finishes this pops up. https://gyazo.com/5271b3770595edf97d40eeff232fd9dd

Is there a way to solve this?
Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here in the last patch version.

I have downloaded latest Android Studio version from https://developer.android.com/studio
and reinstalled

It works fine now :)

Comment: Yeah that solved it. Had to delete it first and then re-install android studio but now it works fine again :P